# PHP array get value from <option value="text">

Tags: php, dns

## PHP Domain Availability Check script

#### The Problem:

There are 70+ domains extensions to check.

#### Solution I'm looking for

I need to check only the extension the client selected in the index.php `<option>` + **.com/.com.br/.net/.org** Those 4 extensions will always be verified, even if the client selected a specific option.

***Working example:***
http://redehost.com.br/registro-de-dominio

I'm looking for something really similar to this /\

index.php

```
<html>

<head>
<title>99points.info : ajax domain name check</title>

<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var loading;
    var results;
    
    form = document.getElementById('form');
    loading = document.getElementById('loading');
    results = document.getElementById('results');
    
    $('#Submit').click( function() {
        
        if($('#Search').val() == "")
        {alert('please enter your domain');return false;}
        
        results.style.display = 'none';
        $('#results').html('');
        loading.style.display = 'inline';
        
        $.post('process.php?domain=' + escape($('#Search').val()),{
        }, function(response){
            
            results.style.display = 'block';
            $('#results').html(unescape(response)); 
            loading.style.display = 'none';
        });
        
        return false;
    });
    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<center>


    
    <form method="post" action="./" id="form"> 
            <div id="registro_box_bg">
            <div id="registro_box">
            <div id="www">www. </div>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Search" name="domain">
                
                    <div id="select" style="background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);">
                    <select id="extensao" name="Extensao"><option value="com">.com</option>
                        <option value="com.br">.com.br</option>
                        <option value="net">.net</option>
                        <option value="org">.org</option>
                        <option value="info">.info</option>
                        <option value="biz">.biz</option>
                        <option value="tv">.tv</option>
                        <option value="name">.name</option>
                        <option value="ws">.ws</option>
                        <option value="cc">.cc</option>
                        <option value="blog.br">.blog.br</option>
                        <option value="flog.br">.flog.br</option>
                        <option value="vlog.br">.vlog.br</option>
                        <option value="wiki.br">.wiki.br</option>
                        <option value="adm.br">.adm.br</option>
                        <option value="adv.br">.adv.br</option>
                        <option value="agr.br">.agr.br</option>
                        <option value="am.br">.am.br</option>
                        <option value="arq.br">.arq.br</option>
                        <option value="art.br">.art.br</option>
                        <option value="ato.br">.ato.br</option>
                        <option value="bio.br">.bio.br</option>
                        <option value="bmd.br">.bmd.br</option>
                        <option value="cim.br">.cim.br</option>
                        <option value="cng.br">.cng.br</option>
                        <option value="cnt.br">.cnt.br</option>
                        <option value="coop.br">.coop.br</option>
                        <option value="ecn.br">.ecn.br</option>
                        <option value="edu.br">.edu.br</option>
                        <option value="eng.br">.eng.br</option>
                        <option value="esp.br">.esp.br</option>
                        <option value="etc.br">.etc.br</option>
                        <option value="eti.br">.eti.br</option>
                        <option value="far.br">.far.br</option>
                        <option value="fm.br">.fm.br</option>
                        <option value="fnd.br">.fnd.br</option>
                        <option value="fot.br">.fot.br</option>
                        <option value="fst.br">.fst.br</option>
                        <option value="g12.br">.g12.br</option>
                        <option value="ggf.br">.ggf.br</option>
                        <option value="gov.br">.gov.br</option>
                        <option value="imb.br">.imb.br</option>
                        <option value="ind.br">.ind.br</option>
                        <option value="inf.br">.inf.br</option>
                        <option value="jor.br">.jor.br</option>
                        <option value="lel.br">.lel.br</option>
                        <option value="mat.br">.mat.br</option>
                        <option value="med.br">.med.br</option>
                        <option value="mil.br">.mil.br</option>
                        <option value="mus.br">.mus.br</option>
                        <option value="net.br">.net.br</option>
                        <option value="nom.br">.nom.br</option>
                        <option value="not.br">.not.br</option>
                        <option value="ntr.br">.ntr.br</option>
                        <option value="odo.br">.odo.br</option>
                        <option value="org.br">.org.br</option>
                        <option value="ppg.br">.ppg.br</option>
                        <option value="pro.br">.pro.br</option>
                        <option value="psc.br">.psc.br</option>
                        <option value="psi.br">.psi.br</option>
                        <option value="qsl.br">.qsl.br</option>
                        <option value="rec.br">.rec.br</option>
                        <option value="slg.br">.slg.br</option>
                        <option value="srv.br">.srv.br</option>
                        <option value="tmp.br">.tmp.br</option>
                        <option value="trd.br">.trd.br</option>
                        <option value="tur.br">.tur.br</option>
                        <option value="tv.br">.tv.br</option>
                        <option value="vet.br">.vet.br</option>
                        <option value="zlg.br">.zlg.br</option>
                        </select>
                            </div>
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
                <!-- falta add 
                
                                            <option value="biz">.biz</option>
                        <option value="tv">.tv</option>
                        <option value="name">.name</option>
                        <option value="ws">.ws</option>
                        <option value="cc">.cc</option> -->
    
    </form>


    <div id="loading">Please wait...<img src="load.gif"></img></div>
        
     <div id="results" style="width:420px; height:600px;" align="left">
        
     </div> 
</div>
        </div>
 
 
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

process.php

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ob_start();

########### Extensions to be checked
$extensions = array(
        '.com'      => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
        '.com.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.net'      => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
        '.org'  => array('whois.pir.org','NOT FOUND'),
    '.info'     => array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND'),
        '.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.blog.br'  => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.flog.br'  => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.vlog.br'  => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.wiki.br'  => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.adm.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.adv.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.agr.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.am.br'    => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.arq.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.ato.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.bio.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.bmd.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.cim.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.cng.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.cnt.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.coop.br'  => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.ecn.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.edu.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.eng.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.esp.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.etc.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.eti.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.far.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.fm.br'    => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.fnd.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.fot.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.fst.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.g12.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
            '.ggf.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.gov.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.imb.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.ind.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.inf.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.jor.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.lel.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.mat.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.med.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.mil.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.mus.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.net.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.nom.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.not.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.ntr.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.odo.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.org.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.ppg.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.pro.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.psc.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.psi.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.qsl.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.rec.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.slg.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.srv.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.tmp.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.trd.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.trd.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.tur.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.tv.br'    => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.vet.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
        '.zlg.br'   => array('whois.registro.br','No match'),
    
    
);
###########

if(isset($_GET['domain']))
{
    $domain = str_replace(array('www.', 'http://'), NULL, $_GET['domain']);
    
    if(strlen($domain) > 0)
    {
        foreach($extensions as $extension => $who)
        {
            $buffer = NULL;
                
            $sock = fsockopen($who[0], 43) or die('Error Connecting To Server:' . $server);
            fputs($sock, $domain.$extension . "\r\n");
                
                while( !feof($sock) )
                {
                    $buffer .= fgets($sock,128);
                }
                
            fclose($sock);
                            
            if(eregi($who[1], $buffer))
            {
                echo '<h4 class="available"><span>Available</span>' . $domain. '<b>' . $extension .'</b> is Available</h4>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<h4 class="taken"><span>Taken</span>' . $domain . '<b>' .$extension .'</b> is Taken</h4>';
            }
            echo '<br />';  
            
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(0.3);
            
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Please enter the domain name';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't post the selected extension to your dataservice (`process.php`).

```
$.post('process.php?domain=' + escape($('#Search').val())
```

Should be

```
$.post('process.php', { domain: escape($('#Search').val()), extension: $('#extensao').val() })
```

Also you have to define which extensions to check in `process.php` and skip extensions which are not in this list.

```
// Add all extensions we need to check to an array
$extensionsToCheck = array('.com', '.com.br', '.net', '.org');
if (isset($_POST['extension']) && !empty($_POST['extension']))
{
    $extensionsToCheck[] = $_POST['extension'];
}   

if(isset($_POST['domain']))
{
    $domain = str_replace(array('www.', 'http://'), NULL, $_POST['domain']);

    if(strlen($domain) > 0)
    {
        foreach($extensions as $extension => $who)
        {
            // Check if we need to check this extensions. Skip if not
            if (!in_array($extension, $extensionsToCheck))
            {
                continue;
            }
```

Something like this should do. Untested

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's almost working I think. Here's the current output: http://oi45.tinypic.com/2q0m3hg.jpg - Maybe I have done something wrong? - **index.php** http://pastebin.com/RKrwWxk3 **process.php** - http://pastebin.com/vifF4gXf

Comment: The extensions in the selectlist have a dot in front, you have to strip that one of. See my edited answer.

Comment: your posting data from ajax and attempting to use _GET to retrieve it rather than _POST

Comment: I have added those trying to fix it, because it wasn't working anyway, you know? Output without dots: http://oi48.tinypic.com/2ijj63b.jpg Current option template: `<option value="ato.br">.ato.br</option>`  -- EDIT I'll try to remove all dots, even from option field, instead of Value. Edit in a few -- EDIT -- Same result :/

Comment: @bizzehdee, he is doing a post request, but the domain and extension are in the uri. It is much better indeed to use jquery post and put those 2 parameters as post data.

Comment: I forgot to put a `&` in the query string to seperate the params. See my updated post. If you stripped the dot from your options now, you have to remove the `substr` from `process.php` as well, but that should be pretty clear.

Comment: with agr.br extension selected -> $extensionsToCheck = `Array ( [0] => .com [1] => .com.br [2] => .net [3] => .org )` $_GET `Array ( [domain] => mydomainextension=agr.br)` where mydomain is the name of the domain I chose, like in the screenshots examples above

Comment: Bram, the script is only working (with the bug above) with this tweak: `$extensionsToCheck = array('.com', '.com.br', '.net', '.org');` - Please take a look at a live demo Your code and the Tweaked version:http://refriautoarcondicionado.com/dominios/ http://refriautoarcondicionado.com/dominios_tweak/

Comment: You are right, in the complete extension list all the extensions are also with dot in front ;), didn't watch it carefully enough. I'll update my answer again and also alter the params to POST as suggested by bizzehdee

Comment: Try my updated answer now please. This should work and be your full solution.

Comment: Thanks for your time Bram!!! Just to be sure this syntax is correct? I feel we're really close to solving this! http://pastebin.com/KaZEASxm

Comment: No it is not correct. See this pastebin, I also indented it so it is better readable. http://pastebin.com/BfYc3EHV

Comment: Hmm, I hate to be annoying, but I'm having some syntax errors here, and I tried some changes but couldn't find the solution: http://oi49.tinypic.com/14mro5t.jpg - Can you see a syntax error?

Comment: Still syntax error - Bro, if you're unconfortable with me asking too many questions and stuff you can say, seriously, I'm feeling annoying right now - http://oi45.tinypic.com/1z6w8qs.jpg

Comment: Hehe no problem dude. I have nothing to do now, and we all started somewhere. But you should try to solve syntax errors yourself. It is not that difficult, just count the opening and closing brackets etc. It's a good lesson to solve this yourself. If it still not works after trying for 15 minutes, come back to me and I'll help you further.